# Oracle JSON column results in invalid identifier when used in a join

Tags: json, oracle, join, view, ora-00904

I've got an Oracle (12c) database as follows:

```
create table t1 (
    id number, tags clob, constraint t1_chk check ( tags is json) enable
);
create table t2 (id number);

create or replace view v1 as 
select ta.id, ta.tags from t1 ta
join t1 tb on ta.id=tb.id;
```

This creates two tables (t1 and t2), and a view (v1) of t1 joined to itself.

When I do some queries on the json column in t1 or v1, the query works as expected:

```
 select t.id, t.tags.foo from t1 t;
 select t.id, t.tags.foo from v1 t;
```

Since I haven't bothered in this example to populate the tables, no rows are returned, but the query works as expected and returns empty rows with two columns, ID and FOO.

However, if I try to join t2, then the query fails with an ORA-00904 invalid identifier error:

```
 select t.id, t.tags.foo, x.id from v1 t
 join t2 x on x.id = t.id

ORA-00904: "T"."TAGS"."FOO": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 55 Column: 15
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get a join like this to work with the json column?

Comment: It seems to work [in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9aea7b892cba23311c30c68c3bf88877). Are you on 12.1 or 12.2, and which patch level? I'd guess it's a known bug from early JSON functionality, and might have a workaround on MoS.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We're running 12.2.0.1.0.